# Function sequence error in PYODBC

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am using `pyodbc` to connect to a database and extract certain data from it.

Here is my code:

```
con = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server= MyServer;database= MyDatabase;trusted_connection=true") 

cursor = con.cursor()

SQL_command = """
                      SELECT RowID = ISNULL
                      (
                          (
                              SELECT TOP 1 RowID
                              FROM [MyDatabase].[admin].[MyTable] 
                              WHERE [queue] = ? and processed IS NULL
                          )
                          ,-1
                      )
                  """

cursor.execute(SQL_command, queueNumber)

cursor.commit()

con.commit()

result_set = cursor.fetchall()
```

And I got following error after I run above code:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

May I know what caused such problem, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe your problem is the strange `commit` statements.  You only need to `commit` when inserting or updating records **not** selecting.

```
cursor.execute(SQL_command, queueNumber)
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
```

Also, in the future when using `commit,` both `cursor.commit` and `con.commit` do the same thing, you only need one.

Finally, I'd get used to calling execute with the second arguement as a tuple:

```
cursor.execute(SQL_command, (queueNumber,))
```

The way you have it works for `pyodbc` but is not DB API standard.

Comment: THANK YOU, very helpful since the documentation for pyodbc is lacking compared to documentation for Matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

I was recieving the two following errors more or less interchangeably:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLGetData)')

pyodbc.Error: ('HY007', '[HY007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Associated statement is not prepared (0) (SQLNumResultCols)')
```

My problem was, that two threads were using the same connection, which led to weird states of the prepared statements. I fixed it by creating a new connection for each thread.